# 'str' object is not callable while accessing 'api/users/'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am using python 3.8 along with rest framework and please find the below details

The following is my serializer for users

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('id', 'username', 'password')
            extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
            Token.objects.create(user=user)
            return user
```

The following the view for the user using the UserSerializer

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated, AllowAny

from .serializers import MovieSerializer, RatingSerializer, UserSerializer

from .models import Movie, Rating

# Create your views here.
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

urls.py(api component)

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("movies", MovieViewSet)
router.register("ratings", RatingViewSet)
router.register("users", UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls))
]

urls.py(main project)

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include("api.urls")),
    path('auth/', obtain_auth_token),
]
```

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/users/

Django Version: 3.0.8
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'api',
 'corsheaders']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 488, in dispatch
    request = self.initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\viewsets.py", line 135, in initialize_request
    request = super().initialize_request(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 390, in initialize_request
    authenticators=self.get_authenticators(),
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 272, in get_authenticators
    return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]
  File "C:\study\fullstack\Movieraterapi\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 272, in <listcomp>
    return [auth() for auth in self.authentication_classes]

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/users/
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
```

Please help me to find the issue the urls working fine for `api/movies/` and `api/ratings/` but when i am trying to access the `api/users` I am getting this error.

Comment: can you add your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings?

Comment: REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": {
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly",
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

settings.py

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {

   'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',

    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',

    ),
}
```

views.py

```
...
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions
...

authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication, ]
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
```

Comment: Can you please explain what all that does and why it would solve the OP's question?